# GridView Calculation On runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Grid With Text Item Templates to insert data from Grid to Database.I have to make some formula on runtime with out postback the page any one canhelp me in which event Can i do this My code is bellow.

```
   For Each gvRow2 As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim txtNetWt As TextBox = CType(gvRow2.FindControl("txtNetWt"), TextBox)
            Dim txtGrossWt As TextBox = CType(gvRow2.FindControl("txtGrossWt"), TextBox)
            Dim txtTareWt As TextBox = CType(gvRow2.FindControl("txtTareWt"), TextBox)
            txtNetWt.Text = Val(txtGrossWt.Text) - Val(txtTareWt.Text)

        Next
```

Comment: Are textboxes added in ItemTemplate or EditeItemTemplate?

Comment: these are added in Item Template and i want to calculate in each row when gross wt and tare wt are entered without refreshing are postbacking page.Thanks

Comment: So you should have to use JavaScript (Ajax).

Comment: How can be used any example please

Comment: You may try Ajax Extension - UpdatePanel.

Comment: How about handling `DataRowBound` event for GridView, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Asp.Net Ajax Extension controls and even better jQuery. Have a look at code - how the JavaScript works:

Markup:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doThat(cells) {
        var result = parseFloat(cells.childNodes[1].value) + parseFloat(cells.childNodes[3].value);
        if (!isNaN(result))
            cells.childNodes[5].value = result;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onchange="doThat(this.parentNode)" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" onchange="doThat(this.parentNode)" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```